# jQuery TinySort mixed literal and numeral not working

Tags: jquery, sorting

Trying to sort the comments on MetaFilter by favorites. Doing this by using TinySort and grabbing the title attribute in the favorites' link:

```
$('div.comments').tsort('span.smallcopy>span>span>a',{attr:'title',order:'desc'});
```

But the mixed literal and numeral is not working correctly as I'm getting this (5, 58, 4, 3, 39, 32, 2...) ex: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmkGD.jpg

instead of (58, 39, 32, 5, 4, 3, 2...)

I am using the latest TinySort version 1.3.27

I have even tried removing the space from the title attribute, no luck:

```
$('span.smallcopy>span>span>a').attr('title', function() {
    return this.title.replace(/\s/g, ''); 
});
```

Comment: What's the result when you remove the `order:'desc'` so it looks like this when you call the `tsort` method `$('div.comments').tsort('span.smallcopy>span>span>a',{attr:'title'});`?

Comment: It doesn't work either without the `order:'desc'` it just becomes (2, 32, 39, 3, 4, 58, 5...)

Comment: can you provide some html-code for us so we can get a bigger picture of your site?

Comment: Not my site, this is for a userscript to be implemented on metafilter.com  Just go to any topic's page to see the DOM structure.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... sounds like a bug I'll have a look tomorrow afternoon and update the source if it is indeed a bug.

-edit-

The @title is a string, since it says something like '4 people marked this as favorite'. So then the sort is technically correct.

If it would have been only a number then tinysort would have parsed it as such and sorted differently.

So a solution here could be to first use jQuery to set an extra attribute using that title and then sort on that. Like this for instance:

```
$('span.smallcopy').find('a:last').each(function(i,el){
    var el=$(this);
    el.attr('data-favorites',parseInt(el.attr('title')));
});
```

And then do the sort.
Haven't tried it yet but maybe you should look into this http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/#returnonlysorted because the source looks rather messy (br right after div :-/ )

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. The next thing I was going to try was to extract just the number out of the attribute, append another tag, then sort based on that.

Comment: Could you provide a more specific uri than just metafilter.com? The site doesn't look anything like your screenshot (I'm seeing something with an #069 background). The only place I'm seeing favorites is here http://www.metafilter.com/home/popularfavorites and these are already sorted serverside (and no span.smallcopy to be found).